# [react-native]onPanResponderRelease on FlatList or ListView doesn't trigger in android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a FlatList component, and I want realize PanResponder API on it, below is part of my code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: ()=>true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: ()=>true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState)=>this.panResponderStart(e, gestureState),
      onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState)=>this.panResponderMove(e, gestureState),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState)=>this.panResponderEnd(e, gestureState),
      onPanResponderTerminate: (e, gestureState)=>this.panResponderEnd(e, gestureState),
    });
}
panResponderEnd(e, gestureState) {
    //this._previousTop += gestureState.dy;
    this.setState({scrollTop:0});
    console.log('release');
}
...
<FlatList
    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    ...
```

`onPanResponderRelease` doesn't trigger on `FlatList` or `ListView` or `VirtualizedList` component, OS is android, is it a RN's bug? how to resolve this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I change the PanResponder on a View , such as <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}><FlatList ...,it works,but it triggers before the gesture is released.

Comment: You can pass the `panHandlers` to `FlatList` as a prop and make it render it with a view by itself. When you say it triggers before release, what do you mean? Is it during movement? While releasing but too early in your taste?

Comment: thanks for your answer.It released during movement when i set panHandlers to view

Answer (score 0):

no need to pass `panHandlers` to view. I am using it directly on `sectionList`.
I got it working properly by using `onPanResponderEnd` instead of `onPanResponderRelease`.

Also if you still want to use `onPanResponderRelease` then you should allow termination request by:

```
onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.